# Link em tabela do DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Eu preciso criar um link onde tenho o nome do insumo na tabela usando o DataTables, esse link deve chamar uma função javascript. O problema é que quando a tabela é carregada ele executa o script para cada linha da tabela, como se todos os links estivesse sendo clicados.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#insumos").dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Insumo/BuscarInsumosDataTable",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "language": {
                "url": "/DataTables/Traducao"
            },
            "aoColumns":
                [
                    {
                        "sName": "InsumoId",
                        "mData": "InsumoId"
                    },
                    {
                        "sName": "Nome",
                        "mData": "Nome",
                        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                            return '<a href="onclick=' + selecionarInsumo(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                ]
        });
    })

    function selecionarInsumo(nome) {
        alert("deu certo, " + nome)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Olá. Consegue fazer um exemplo no jsfiddle? Fica muito mais facil ajudar.

Comment: Tiago, ta lá, https://jsfiddle.net/Alan_Almeida/exoe3qwc/13/ eu comentei algumas linhas por que são de recursos do meu servidor, e com elas não estava funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava a "simular os clicks" porque ao preencher a tabela estava a invocar a função.

Quando está a escrever.:
`return '<a href="onclick=' + selecionarInsumo(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';`

O selecionarInsumo(data) é uma função javascript e portanto vai correr de imediato.

1º constrangimento encontrado foi no atributo href.
Está iniciado mas não está finalizado portanto é necessário mudar de
href=" 
para
href="#"
Se pretender que não encaminhe para nenhum lado.

Quando é lido o atributo onclick é considerado javascript portanto para correr como pretende tem ficar assim.:

```
return '<a href="#" onclick="selecionarInsumo(\''+data+'\');">' + data + '</a>';
```

Neste return dentro do onclick o que se pretende é texto e não a função mas quando for acionado o onclick vai interpretar javascript.

O jsfiddle com as alterações.:
https://jsfiddle.net/exoe3qwc/15/
Por algum motivo o selecionarInsumo não é identificado no jsfiddle, mas testei com uma pagina e correu a 100%.

Comment: Tiago, obrigado, realmente não tinha pensado nisso, o return tem que retornar tudo como texto...

Comment: O exemplo postado no jsfiddle não  está funcionando e eu preciso fazer algo parecido, inclusive criei um post http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151100/link-com-imagem-no-datatables-net.

Comment: @Adriano SUV Não funciona porque dá erro selecionarlnsumo, mas se criar uma pagina em html e colocar o codigo que está no jsfiddle, irá funcionar.